# How can i use google-cloud-storage to have public users download an injury form

Tags: reactjs, firebase, localhost, google-cloud-storage

When the button is clicked it does not cause a download when I run this through localhost. I am unsure why.

What I want is the button in the HTML aspect of react to cause a download of the docx file "injury form"

import React from 'react';
    import firebase from "firebase";

```
const Documents = () =>{


    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var docsRef = storage.ref('Documents/Injury form.docx');

    const Download = () => { 

        docsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        }).catch(function(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'storage/object-not-found':
                  // File doesn't exist
                  break;

                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                  // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                  break;

                case 'storage/canceled':
                  // User canceled the upload
                  break;


                case 'storage/unknown':
                  // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
                  break;
              }
            });

            }
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={Download}>yoooo</button>d        
    </div>
)
}

export default Documents
```

I have also configured the Cloud Storage bucket for cross-origin access (CORS). as stated here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does not activate the download. It creates a link to the download URL.

you would need to put a variable in the function to equal the URL that is passed through it. In this case done through the useState() hook.

```
 const [download, setDownload] = useState("blank");

        var storage = firebase.storage();
        var docsRef = storage.ref('Documents/Injury form.docx');

    docsRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        setDownload(
            url
        )

    })
```

Then pass this through

```
<a href={download}>the link to download it
```

If the method used did not work, you can go to the firebase console and right-click on the file uploaded to the storage area. Take the URL for download from there and create an

```
<a href="<your URL>"> Button </a>
```

This will create a link or button that will activate the download.

in this case allowing users to download the injury form for the phisio website.